# Appending empty list to numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to figure out how to append an empty list to an already existing numpy array

can I get an array for any list b

```
a = np.array([b])
a = np.append(a, [])
print a # you get array([a, []])
```

this code just outputs the original [a] instead of [a, []]. Does anyone know how this is achieved?

Comment: What do you expect `a.shape` to be after appending?

Comment: This makes no sense, you cannot change the shape of matrix

Comment: a.shape = (2L,) @shx2

Comment: So you start with a 3-dim array and you expect it to be 1dim after appending?...  You clearly got some notion wrong here...

Comment: Yes, I'm not to worried about the [1, 2] I just want to append an empty list to it np.array([[], []])

Comment: If you store the list in a (1,) shape array and append that it works

Comment: not for me I've put it into every shape I can and it does not seem to work @PaulPanzer

Comment: Changed the question to make it more general

Comment: Hm, could you do me a favour and try `b=np.ndarray([None]); b[0]=[]; np.append(a, b)`. I assure you that works for me.

Comment: This worked for me thank you @PaulPanzer but I used np.array([None]) instead of ndarray

Comment: Yep, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can have an empty list in array is to make an object dtype array.

```
In [382]: a = np.empty((3,),dtype=object)
In [383]: a
Out[383]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [384]: a[0]=[1,2,3]
In [385]: a[1]=[]
In [386]: a
Out[386]: array([[1, 2, 3], [], None], dtype=object)
```

or from a list of lists (of varying length)

```
In [393]: np.array([[1,2,3],[]])
Out[393]: array([[1, 2, 3], []], dtype=object)
```

You can concatenate one object array to another:

```
In [394]: a = np.empty((1,),object); a[0]=[1,2,3]
In [395]: a
Out[395]: array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=object)
In [396]: b = np.empty((1,),object); b[0]=[]
In [397]: b
Out[397]: array([[]], dtype=object)
In [398]: np.concatenate((a,b))
Out[398]: array([[1, 2, 3], []], dtype=object)
```

`np.append` wraps `concatenate`, and is designed to add a scalar to another array.  What it does with a list, empty or otherwise, is unpredictable.

---

I take that last comment back; `np.append` turns the list into a simple array.  These all do the same thing

```
In [413]: alist=[1,2]
In [414]: np.append(a,alist)
Out[414]: array([[1, 2, 3], 1, 2], dtype=object)
In [415]: np.concatenate((a, np.ravel(alist)))
Out[415]: array([[1, 2, 3], 1, 2], dtype=object)
In [416]: np.concatenate((a, np.array(alist)))
Out[416]: array([[1, 2, 3], 1, 2], dtype=object)
```